# code is not checking second elsif condition in ruby

Tags: ruby, control-flow

My code is returning the 1st statement in control-flow

```
a = 6
b = 13
c = 4
if a == 2||4||5 && b == 9||10||11
puts "staement1"
elsif a == 6||7||8 && b == 12||13||14
puts "statement2"
elsif puts c
end
```

output is "statement1" but it should be "statement2". what is the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if is like

```
a = 6
b = 13
if (a == 2)||4||5 && (b == 9)||10||11
```

so in the end

```
4 && 10
```

and this is `true` because the only falsey values in ruby are `nil` and `false` itself

maybe what you want is something like

```
if [2, 4, 5].include?(a) && [9, 10, 11].include?(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets talk about `a == 2 || 4 || 5`.

It isn't equivalent to `a == 2 || a == 4 || a == 5`, but is evaluated in such order:

1. `a == 2` is `false`
2. `false || 4` is 4
3. `4 || 5` is not evaluated and short circuited.

Therefore, `a == 2 || 4 || 5`'s value is 4...

The same rule applies for `b == 9||10||11` ... etc.

Comment: "if a == 2||4||5 && b == 9||10||11" overall this statement is false. so ,program should check the second statement right "elsif a == 6||7||8 && b == 12||13||14"?

Comment: @code_t  Since `statement1` is printed, the truth must be `a==2||4||5 && b==9||10||1` is evaluated to `true`.  And `4 && 10` is `true` indeed.

Comment: @halfelf nitpicking:  `4 && 10` is `4`, not `true`. But `4` is _truthy_ in ruby, that’s correct.

Comment: I don't understand why you list #3 since it is not evaluated.